# How to make Eircode/postcode a required field in woocommerce checkout

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-checkout-fields

Looking to make the Eircode/Postcode field on the woocommerce checkout page mandatatory with the red astrisks beside it just like it is for the other fields. This is because we ship to Ireland and some couriers won't accept the order without an eircode. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Preferably with Woocommerce code snippets plugin?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfcwH.png)